# reading a string from file

Tags: bash, shell

I want to read a string from file and print it as follow :

```
LINE=tr '\n' ' ' < $FILENAME
x1=$LINE
echo $LINE
```

but the command `echo $LINE` display an empty line ?

Comment: Now saying that would give error, won't it?  Use command substitution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As already pointed out by the other posters, to embed the output of the `tr` command into another command (in this case `LINE=...`), surround the `tr` command by `$(...)`. In bash this is known as [command substitution](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Command-Substitution).

```
LINE=$(tr '\n' ' ' < "$FILENAME")
```

In case you intend to use `$LINE` as a sequence of parameters for subsequent commands (in this case `echo`), then newlines are eventually replaced by space during [word splitting](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Word-Splitting). This would make `tr` superfluous; you might as well do this:

```
LINE=$(cat "$FILENAME")
```

or even better:

```
LINE=$(< "$FILENAME")
```

Word splitting is not effective inside double quotes; so `echo "$LINE"` would still require `tr` to remove newlines.

Comment: `$(...)` does NOT replace newlines with spaces - the only thing it does is trim *trailing* newlines (however many). Your alternate solutions therefore do not work as intended. Also, please double-quote the `$FILENAME` references.

Comment: @mklement0: You are right; the truth about disappearing newlines is a bit more complicated. I made an edit to rephrase that.

Comment: Thanks for the edit, but it is important to note that word splitting is NOT involved during *variable assignment* - if the contents of `$FILENAME` has *interior* newlines, they *will* end up in the value of `$LINE`. It is only when you later *reference* `$LINE` *without quoting* that word splitting occurs - along with other shell expansions such as globbing, which may or may not be desired.

Comment: Thanks, I hope my edits sufficiently reflect your comments. Whether or not word splitting is applicable, depends entirely on the context (how will `$LINE` be used). OP was not explicit about that, so everybody will have to make up his own mind there.

Comment: Thanks - between your edits and this comment thread I think we've got it covered.

Answer (score 2):

You should be using **command substitution** like this:

```
LINE=$(tr '\n' ' ' < "$FILENAME")
```

But this will store tr's output into `LINE` variable.

Comment: the problem was fixed , but what is the diffrence ?

Comment: `Command substitution` has a syntax which is either back-tick OR `$(..)`

Comment: @user3137879: If you assign without `$(...)` (or backticks), you assign a *string literal* to `LINE`. Command substitution means that the string enclosed in `$(...)` is interpreted as a command and executed, and its *result* is then assigned to `LINE`.

Comment: Thanks @mklement0 for your edit and explanation. OP: Sorry I was on phone with my client so couldn't explain it properly. See this link for ore details: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command_substitution

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to put the call to the `tr` command with backquotes:

```
LINE=`tr '\n' ' ' < $FILENAME`
```

Comment: Works, but use of backquotes is deprecated in favor of the `$(...)` syntax - the latter has the advantage that it can be nested.